# how can i use saving data in OSM iD editor

Tags: javascript, save, geospatial, openstreetmap

I use OSM iD editor for my own project running on Apache and I render my own tiles.

But the problem is, I don't know how to save changes (includes adding or drawing nodes, path, and street name) to my own server. I don't want to save changes into the OSM server.

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of details. Did you install the complete [rails port](https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website/)? Did you change the iD editor accordingly to point at your API instead of the official one?

Comment: @scai I want to use this editor with my own tiles and when I add some changes or creating some path or point I want to save these changes on my own server not openstreetmap.org. can you help me with this. another question should i install rails port?

Comment: Yes, you have to if you want editing-support. But if you don't need the whole world but just want to create/edit a small area, then consider using a different editor such as JOSM and just edit a local .osm file instead. This will be much easier than installing and maintaining a complete OSM infrastructure.

Comment: @scai Thank you so much. JOSM is local but i want web-based editor. i just need the data respond to server that you click on save button and after that save those data on my own server i couldn't find those codes.